# Arguments Definition To Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript

This might be an easy question to answer for an experienced developer! I'm somehow caught in a code loophole where I need to define everything before sending to contract. As you can see I do define transaction, but the argument count that's needed require 3 also need to be defined prior. I'm unsure which code to write to make this work. So at the moment I'm getting ReferenceError: transaction is not defined. I'm still learning a lot about smart contract programming and how to connect to it with js. Thanks a bunch in advance!

```
    async function createSale(nftContract, url) {

      const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
      const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const auth = undefined;
      const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, provider);
      const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(nftmarketaddress, Market.abi, provider);
      const data = await marketContract.fetchMarketItems();
      console.log(auth); // undefined
  
      // ✅ No error
      console.log(auth?.user?.name); // undefined

      //let contract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, Market.abi, signer);
      const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(formInput.price, 'ether');
      const newPrice = price.toString()
      console.log(newPrice); // price
    
      //console.log(tokenId); // tokenid
      const decimals = 18;
      const input = "999"; // Note: this is a string, e.g. user input
      //const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits(input, decimals);

      let contract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, signer)

      let tx = await transaction.wait()
      let event = tx.events[0]
      let value = event.args[2]
      let tokenId = value.toNumber()
      const itemId = tokenId;
    
      transaction = await contract.putItemToResell(
        nftContract, itemId, { value: (listingPrice) }
      )

      let listingPrice = await contract.getListingPrice()
      listingPrice = listingPrice.toString()

        await transaction.wait()
        router.push('/')
    }

    return (

      
    <div className="modal" onClick={props.onClose}>
      <div className="modal-content" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>


      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <div className="px-4" style={{ maxWidth: '1600px' }}>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4 pt-4">
            {
              nfts.map((nft, i) => (
                <div key={i} className="border shadow rounded-xl overflow-hidden">
                  <img src={nft.image} />
                  <div className="p-4">

                    <input type ="text" style={{ height: '20px' }} className="text-1xl font-semibold" value= {nft.name} readOnly = {true}/></div>
                    <div style={{ height: '20px', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                   
                  </div>
                  <div className="p-4 bg-black">
                  <input placeholder="Asset Price in Matic" className= "mt-2 border rounder p-4" onChange={e => updateFormInput({...formInput, price: e.target.value})} />

                    <button className="mt-4 w-full bg-pink-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-12 rounded hover:bg-pink-300" onClick={() => createSale(nft)}>List</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={props.onClose} className="button">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
   
  );


};
 
export default ModalRelist;
```

And here the smart contract function:

```
function putItemToResell(address nftContract, uint256 itemId, uint256 newPrice)
        public
        payable
        nonReentrant
        onlyItemOwner(itemId)
    {
        uint256 tokenId = idToMarketItem[itemId].tokenId;
        require(newPrice > 0, "Price must be at least 1 wei");
        require(
            msg.value == listingPrice,
            "Price must be equal to listing price"
        );
        //instantiate a NFT contract object with the matching type
        NFT tokenContract = NFT(nftContract);
        //call the custom transfer token method   
        tokenContract.transferToken(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);

        address payable oldOwner = idToMarketItem[itemId].owner;
        idToMarketItem[itemId].owner = payable(address(0));
        idToMarketItem[itemId].seller = oldOwner;
        idToMarketItem[itemId].price = newPrice;
        idToMarketItem[itemId].sold = false;
        _itemsSold.decrement();

        emit ProductListed(itemId);
    }

function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory){
    uint itemCount = _itemIds.current();
    uint unsoldItemCount = _itemIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
    uint currentIndex = 0;

    MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++){
        if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == address(0)){
            uint currentId = idToMarketItem [i+1].itemId;
            MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
            items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            currentIndex +=1;
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to mark the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coz you are defining transactions after writing the line

```
 let tx = await transaction.wait()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I decide to use this technique. I did this because a friend told me to, and I think you should too. I think that a smart contract should have a clear set of arguments to make sure it is carried out correctly. This will help make sure that the contract is safe and that everyone knows what the terms of the agreement.